# enumitem: setting labelsep for description affect the list of other type inside it

Tags: lists, enumitem

When I use a `oversize` tcolorbox as the description label, the default `labelsep` is not big enough, as a result the label and the text may stick together when the label is long. As an attempt to fix this, with the package `enumitem`, I set this `labelsep` to be `1em` so as to ensure that there is at least this amount of distance between the description label and the text.

However, I notice that, even if my setting was specifically for `description` (via `\setlist[description]`), the setting may interfere with other type of lists inside it. Below is a MWE (I have set the `labelsep` very large so that the result can be easily seen):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\setlist[description]{labelsep=3cm}
% \setlist[itemize]{labelsep=1cm}

\begin{description}
    \item[label] first level
    \begin{itemize}
        \item second level
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item second level
    \end{enumerate}
\end{description}

\begin{itemize}
    \item first level
    \begin{description}
        \item[label] second level
    \end{description}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder if there is some way to avoid this interaction. It seems that one could have resolved this by setting the `labelsep` for other type of list simultaneously. However, since I only wish to change the behavior of `description` and (more importantly) don't know what the exact current value would be for the other type of lists, it would be hard for me to touch this value without changing the appearance for other lists. Thus is there some way to fix this without having to modify the setting for other type of lists?

---

**ADD:**

The reason for me to use `description` was that I would like my text following the label to be properly indented. Thus I don't want the other type of lists to be affected inside a `description` because I wasn't really using/thinking of this outer `description` as a list.

I tried to achieve the same effect with `\hangindent` or `\leftskip` but without total success — if the text following it contains a `\par` (manually given by user), then the indented behavior would be aborted.

Comment: This is how lists work ;). It isn't changing the settings for the other lists. Those settings are defined so they are context sensitive. So placement at level 2 always depends on what happens at level 1. Normally, that's what you want. I can't help thinking you're misusing `description` here. A gap of 3cm would make it much harder for people to immediately read on from the label. Why use `description` here at all?

Comment: @cfr You are probably right. The use of `description` was because that I would like my text following the label to be properly indented, but now I think about it, perhaps the right choice would be to use `\hangindent`.

Comment: perhaps you could add a hand sketch of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation notes that `\labelsep` is passed through. You can reset it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\newlength\mylabelsep
\setlength\mylabelsep{\labelsep}
\setlist[description]{labelsep*=3cm,itemindent=!}
\setlist[2]{labelsep=\mylabelsep,labelwidth=!}


\begin{description}
    \item[label] first level \lipsum[1]
    \begin{itemize} 
        \item second level \lipsum[1]
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item second level
    \end{enumerate}
\end{description}

\begin{itemize}
    \item first level
    \begin{description}
        \item[label] second level
    \end{description}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

But I would simply not use the oversize option. It doesn't make sense to tell LaTeX that the label is smaller than it is in reality and then to work around the problem the lie produce.

Comment: Thank you for this! By the way, I was using the `oversize` option so as to avoid the outer tcolorbox from affecting the position/alignment of the label text.